# Matplotlib xticks gathered at one end of axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My xticks has started acting up and I cannot locate the issue. The ticks used to be spread out over the x-axis, but now they're all gathered at the end:

[image: current plot]

Snippet:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(df_20796674_sum2['TIMESTAMP'], df_20796674_sum2['Pressure'], label ='Pressure')
plt.plot(df_20796674_sum2['TIMESTAMP'], df_20796674_sum2['Time-series'], label = ' Model')
plt.xticks(x[::1500])
plt.legend()
```

Comment: Sample data (in tabular format or as the result of `df_20796674_sum2.head().to_dict()`, would help produce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Create a [reprex]. We can't run your code bc we don't know what `df_20796674_sum2` contains.

Comment: When you say it used to work, what is now different that means it's not now working? Is it a different dataset or have you changed the plotting code?

Comment: The correct way to plot the a dataframe is with `pandas.DataFrame.plot`. Make sure `'TIMESTAMP'` is a datetime with `df_20796674_sum2['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df_20796674_sum2['TIMESTAMP'])` if it's not already a datetime Dtype. Then `ax = df_20796674_sum2.plot(x='TIMESTAMP', y=['Pressure', 'Time-series'], figsize=(10, 7))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of plt.xticks() specifies the ticks location. I'm not sure what values your x variable contains and how they relate to e.g. df_20796674_sum2['TIMESTAMP'].

I think you want to achieve that some timestamps are shown on the x-axis at the ticks locations. So, if you have a list of values (pressures) that correspond with a list of timestamps, you would plot the pressures, and then add the xticks at the specified indices (here: each second timestamp is a xtick). Some minimal code (didn't test it):

```
timestamps = ["2022-08-01", "2022-08-02", "2022-08-03", "2022-08-04", "2022-08-05"]
pressures = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1]

plt.plot(pressures, label="Pressure")
plt.xticks(
    ticks=list(range(5))[::2],
    labels=timestamps[::2]
)
```